# In VSTO Addin for Excel how to handle a button click event from active worksheet?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, vsto, excel-addins

Currently I am developing an Excel 2010 Addin using VB.NET 2010 with VSTO.

The active worksheet has a button, its click event will be handled by its own VBA code.

Now I would like to handle the same button click event in Addin without affecting its original VBA function. Is it possible? And how can I achieve this?

The pre-requisite of this task is that nothing is allowed to be changed on the Excel Template (including its VBA code). That's why I am trying from the event handling by VB.NET.

The trigger point is that the button in the Excel template is clicked, then it will surely raise certain event, and such event will certainly be handled by VBA macro, but I would like to add another listener (event handler) in VB.Net to the same event, so I can do some additional task.

Is there anyone know how to add such event handler?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I see the point, but you'd make a company visible class in the addin to say application.run(macro name,args) then call that so addin.com class.function to run macro in .net or do you mean migrate the function to .net or handle the click in addin not like _click() in VBA???

Comment: No migration intended, just want to use that particular button click event to trigger the Addin to do some additional task. The existing excel template is an approved form (with Macro), I am not allowed to change anything of it.

Comment: Just noticed auto correct changed make a com visible to make a company.   My solution of Application.Run(x,y,z) from VB.NET should do it.   In the past i've created the functions in a non exposed class, then created an exposed wrapper to call these, so the non exposed function would be clsFunctions.fnCLICK_BUTTON and the exposed would be clsVBAFunctions.fnCallVBAButton click, which would be called from VBA

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but the pre-requisite of this task is that nothing can be changed on the Excel Template (including its vba code). That's why I am trying from the event handling by VB.NET.

Comment: I'm lost :) You cant get AddIn to do the call to the existing function if you dont tell it to somehow?

Comment: The trigger point is that the button in the excel template is clicked, then it will surely raise certain event, and such event will certainly be handled by VBA macro, but I would like to add another listener (event handler) in VB.Net to the same event, so I can do some additional task.

Comment: I think whether this is possible or not will depend on what KIND of button control is involved. If it's an ActiveX CommandButton then it's probably possible since these buttons become properties/objects of the worksheet, through which they can be accessed. Also, they expose events via that OLEFormat.Object interface. That's not the case with the "form field" buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be3ed2fd-f111-4a10-a306-0920b93cabe5/how-to-add-a-button-control-to-an-excel-worksheet-using-c?forum=exceldev) was a similar question.

```
var cmdButton = (Excel.Shape)xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.CommandButton.1", Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 60, 60, 60, 60);

cmdButton.Name = "btnClick";

//var cmdBtn = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton)Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet((Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveSheet, null, "btnClick", new object[0], null, null, null);

var cmdBtn = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.CommandButton)Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet((Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveSheet, null, "btnClick", new object[0], null, null, null);
//
//some button formatting codes
//
cmdBtn.Click +=cmdBtn_Click;


void cmdBtn_Click()// Command button click event handler
{
  MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

In your case it is easier, you don't need to create a button, you can just use it's name.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will try your approach in VB.NET, just have one concern, will the event handler in the Addin overwrite the event handler in its original VBA module? I need both handler works.

Comment: I think it keeps the original event handler, but even if i'm wrong - you can invoke this macro from your vb.net event handler

Comment: Alex, Sorry for not replying you soon, I have tested the method in VB.NET, get stuck in "cmdBtn.Click +=cmdBtn_Click;"
Don't know how to convert this line to VB.NET.

Then I create a new Addin project in C#, your code works perfect. The click event are handled by both handlers.

Comment: I would like to make this great approach to work in VB.NET also.
Can you give some advice on "cmdBtn.Click +=cmdBtn_Click;"?
How can I convert it to VB.NET. Thanks.

Comment: Now the event handling sequence is as follows: (1) VBA handler (2) C#.NET handler.  Is it possible to let the C#.NET handler run first?